# C - request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

Context: I'm trying to make a few modifications for a game called Grand Theft Auto V.

I'm using `GET_ENTITY_COORDS` function to get the coordinates of a entity in the game:

```
static Inline struct Vector3 GET_ENTITY_COORDS(Entity entity, BOOL alive) {
    args[0] = entity;
    args[1] = alive;
    invokeNative(0x3FEF770D40960D5A);
    struct Vector3 vector3 = { *(float*)&rets[0], *(float*)&rets[1], *(float*)&rets[2] };
    return vector3;
}
```

This should return `xPos`, `yPos` and `zPos`.

---

Now this is the code what I currently are struggling with:

```
#include "gta.h"

void invokeNative_s(u64 hash) {
    struct Native_s** g_Natives = (struct Native_s**)NativeTableAddress;
    struct Native_s* Natives = g_Natives[hash & 0xFF];
    while (Natives != 0) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Natives->NativeCount; i++) {
            if (Natives->NativeHashes[i] == hash) {
                ((void(*)(struct NativeArg_s*))Natives->NativeFunctions[i])((struct NativeArg_s*)FreeSpaceAddress);
                return;
            }
        }
        Natives = Natives->LastNativeTable;
    }
}

struct gtaVars_s {
    BOOL init;
    int frameCount;
};

static struct gtaVars_s *gtaVars = (struct gtaVars_s*)FreeSpaceAddress+0x100;

BOOL nativeHook() {
    if (!gtaVars->init) {
        nativeArg->ArgValues = args;
        nativeArg->ReturnValue = rets;
        gtaVars->frameCount = 0;
        gtaVars->init = TRUE;
    }

    int newFrameCount = GET_FRAME_COUNT();
    if (gtaVars->frameCount < newFrameCount) {
        gtaVars->frameCount = newFrameCount;

        Ped pedID = PLAYER_PED_ID();
        Player playerID = PLAYER_ID();

        /* define player coords */
        Vector3 playerCoords = GET_ENTITY_COORDS(pedID, 1);
        char waterRadius = 10;

        SET_SUPER_JUMP_THIS_FRAME(playerID);
        SET_PLAYER_INVINCIBLE(playerID, TRUE);

        if (IS_CONTROL_JUST_PRESSED(0, Button_Tpad)) {
            // teleport to beach
            SET_ENTITY_COORDS(pedID, -1374.881, -1398.835, 6.141, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE);

            // set water
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x, playerCoords.y, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x+2, playerCoords.y, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x, playerCoords.y+2, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x+2, playerCoords.y+2, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x+4, playerCoords.y, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x, playerCoords.y+4, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x+4, playerCoords.y+4, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x+6, playerCoords.y, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x, playerCoords.y+6, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x+6, playerCoords.y+6, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x+8, playerCoords.y, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x, playerCoords.y+8, waterRadius, 10);
            MODIFY_WATER(playerCoords.x+8, playerCoords.y+8, waterRadius, 10);
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

But I'm getting multiple errors from the `GET_ENTITY_COORDS` function even though I have defined the function above in my script:

```
source/gta.c:42:3: error: unknown type name ‘Vector3’
   Vector3 playerCoords = GET_ENTITY_COORDS(pedID, 1);
   ^
source/gta.c:42:26: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘int’ using type ‘struct Vector3’
   Vector3 playerCoords = GET_ENTITY_COORDS(pedID, 1);
                          ^
source/gta.c:53:29: error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union
```

Does anybody know what the cause of this error is, and how I can fix it? I would appreciate it a lot since I'm struggling with this for quite some days and would love to see it resolved, thank you in advance.

Comment: `Vector3` => `struct Vector3` should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as shown in some of your snippets `Vector3` is used like:

```
static Inline struct Vector3 GET_ENTITY_COORDS
```

So, since this works, it means that it's defined (in some code we don't see) as `struct`, but not as `typedef struct` (which would allow to use it without `struct` keyword).

your error is when declaring your variable as `Vector3`:

```
Vector3 playerCoords = GET_ENTITY_COORDS(pedID, 1);
```

should be

```
struct Vector3 playerCoords = GET_ENTITY_COORDS(pedID, 1);
```

the rest of the errors are just a consequence of that one. The parser is lost at this point.